# Pandas - Python -Error -> #pragma:no cover pandas_datareader._utils.RemoteDataError: Data not available

Tags: python, arrays, csv, pandas, yahoo-finance

I am attempting to make an options screener that searches for options contracts with a minimum level of volume and returns the options symbol based on a list of ticker symbols located in a .csv file. Everything works fine when the .csv file contains only a few symbols but when I add over 6000 symbols to the list it breaks down and gives me the following message:

**'pragma:no cover pandas_datareader._utils.RemoteDataError: Data not available'**

I suspected that it might be the sheer volume of queries made to yahoo that is causing the trouble. I even added time.sleep() of 10 seconds between calls but still no luck.

Any information on what this is and how to fix it would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks for the help

Comment: would the code help?

Answer (score 0):

Yahoo changed the format of their site, so the pandas-datareader's scraper is temporarily broken. See [github.com/pydata/pandas-datareader/issues/212](http://github.com/pydata/pandas-datareader/issues/212)